# O que é observabilidade e quais são seus benefícios em relação a sistemas de software?

Tags: terminologia, engenharia-de-software, observabilidade

Ando [lendo a respeito do termo](https://stackoverflow.blog/2021/09/08/observability-is-key-to-the-future-of-software-and-your-devops-career/) *Observabilidade* em relação ao campo da computação e sistemas de softwares, e junto com esse termo me surgem outros termos que são: *Sistema de Observabilidade*, *Telemetria* e assim por diante. Não sei se isto é algum conceito novo ou antigo e que "ressurgiu das cinzas".

Ainda não está claro para mim de forma precisa o que é Observabilidade no contexto de sistemas de softwares, portanto, eu gostaria de ter as seguintes dúvidas esclarecidas:

- O que é Observabilidade?
- Qual a vantagem da Observabilidade e o que ela traz de benefício para sistemas de software?
- O que seria um Sistema de Observabilidade?
- Qual a relação da Telemetria com a Observabilidade?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Está bem na moda, né? Bem, não posso dizer que é modinha, tem uma função importante. Em alguns casos abusa-se, mas em geral é interessante.

> observabilidade ( ob·ser·va·bi·li·da·de )
>
> nome feminino Qualidade do que é observável (ex.: observabilidade da
> informação; observabilidade do comportamento).
>
> etimologiaOrigem etimológica:forma alatinada de observável + -dade.
> Palavras relacionadas observável observavelmente radiante quantização
> metagaláxia fenótipo fenotipicamente observável ( ob·ser·vá·vel )
>
> adjectivo de dois géneros
>
> 1. Que pode ser visto ou observado.
> 2. Que merece ser observado.
> 3. Que pode ser medido de forma directa (ex.: grandeza observável).
>
> nome masculino
> 4. Quantidade ou grandeza que se pode medir directamente.
>
> etimologiaOrigem etimológica:observar + -ável.
>
> "observabilidade", in Dicionário Priberam da Língua Portuguesa [em
> linha], 2008-2023, https://dicionario.priberam.org/observabilidade.

E temos definições mais específicas, como na matemática (tem gente que ainda acha que não precisa saber matemática para programar):

> Observabilidade, na teoria de controle, é uma medida do quão bem podem os
> estados de um sistema ser inferidos a partir do conhecimento de suas
> saídas externas. A observabilidade e a controlabilidade de um sistema
> são conceitos matemáticos duais.
>
> Formalmente, um sistema é dito ser observável se, para qualquer
> possível sequência de vetores de estado e de controle, o estado atual
> pode ser determinado em tempo finito usando apenas as saídas (esta
> definição é voltada à representação no espaço de estados. Menos
> formalmente, isto significa que a partir de saídas do sistema é
> possível determinar o comportamento de todo o sistema. Se um sistema
> não é observável, isto significa que os valores atuais de alguns de
> seus estados não podem ser determinados através dos sensores de saída:
> isso implica que o seu valor é desconhecido para o controlador e,
> consequentemente, que ele não será capaz de cumprir as especificações
> de controle referente a estas saídas.

[Fonte](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observabilidade). [Melhor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observability).

De uma certa forma sempre se usou isso. Mais recentemente se formalizou mais a definição, o termo entrou na boca das pessoas e passou ter inúmeras ferramentas para auxiliar, da mesma forma que tem para testes, depuração, etc.

Quanto mais você tem sistemas funcionando 24x7 (missão crítica, ou quase isso) mais se torna necessário saber se tudo está correto. Quanto mais tem usuários que você não tem contato direto para te informar de problemas no software, mais você tem que descobrir isso através de verificação pelo próprio software.

Em computação a observabilidade é a característica que algo tem para poder ser monitorado. Indica se tem meios de descobrir o que está acontecendo ou aconteceu com o software quando estava sendo executado.

Difere de testes porque é usado em produção e espera-se que nunca identifique anomalias, ainda que isso acabe sendo comum ter.

E também não é só sobre perceber erros, mas falhas que não são do software, ataques, uso fora do normal, e prover medições para tomar decisões em relação a uma série de coisas, de infraestrutura ou até mudanças de arquitetura.

Os mecanismos mais comuns para fazer isso é o *logging*, o *tracing* e *profiling*.

É fundamental em cenários de [SRE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Site_reliability_engineering), algo que explodiu recentemente.

Embora seja melhor em sistemas mais críticos e grandes, qualquer implantação pode se beneficiar, até mesmo como forma de auditoria, ainda que não seja o propósito principal. Claro que sistemas distribuídos serão mais beneficiados. Como esses sistemas são complexos sem isso há muitos riscos e dificuldade de traçar um mapa do que está acontecendo ou aconteceu. Mesmo com informações pode complicar, por isso sistemas distribuídos devem ser evitados até que seja absolutamente necessário.

Com algo observável é possível sanar problemas mais facilmente porque você tem dados, ou prevenir que problemas aconteçam porque dados já indicam um padrão que resultará em algo ruim.

Em geral, além do monitoramento, estabelece-se métricas do que é considerado normal e anormal, quando emitir alertas ou tomar ações proativas para mitigar algum possível problema.

O termo principal é praticamente sinônimo de telemetria e monitoramento. Em tese a telemetria seria algo remoto, mas não vejo isso como algo tão relevante, seria preciosismo determinar uma diferença, ainda que na prática quase sempre será remoto mesmo. Você precisa da observavilidade na solução para conseguir esses dois outros.

Sistema de observabilidade eu imagino ser uma solução que fornece ferramentas necessárias para coletar, armazenar, gerenciar e visualizar os dados vindos das soluções principais que estão rodando. Há toda uma indústria investindo em ferramentas deste tipo.

O termo costuma implicar que tudo é feito o tempo todo sem muita intervenção humana, diferente de outras formas de monitoramento mais simples e pontuais, com um objetivo mais específico.

Ela é fundamental para garantir alta disponibilidade.